# Javascript memory leak deleting Raphael path objects

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, raphael

I have a memory leak in my code and I cannot figure out what is causing it.  I am receiving target data from a `WebSocket` which contains basically an ID and an X,Y coordinate.  The data is passed to a `HandleData` function which creates a circle for each target and a line (which is updated) to show where the target has moved from/to.

If a target no longer appears in the `WebSocket` stream it is removed.  On testing I have found the webpage quickly amasses hundreds of mb of data in spite of me removing these items.  Upon using Chrome's memory profiler it seems Raphael (or something) is holding onto all the path information in spite of me deleting it.

If anyone can help me in anyway I would be very grateful.  It does seem that Raphael is holding onto the data but there is every chance I have made a mistake somewhere in my code :)

```
var arrayColours = ["#f33", "#3f3", "#33f", "#f66", "#6f6", "#66f"];

var targetStructArray = [];

function HandleTargetData(data) {

    //Go through all our existing targets and mark them as not updated
    for (var i = 0; i < targetStructArray.length; i++) {
        targetStructArray[i].updated = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.targets.length; i++) {
        var targetData = data.targets[i];
        var targetStruct = undefined;

        //find our targetStruct
        for (var j = 0; j < targetStructArray.length; j++) {
            if (targetStructArray[j].id == targetData.id) {
                targetStruct = targetStructArray[j];
                break;
            }
        }

        //If it doesnt exist, create it
        if (!targetStruct) {
            var path = paper.path();

            path.attr({ "stroke-width": "2", "stroke": "#888" });
            path.addPart(['M', targetData.x, targetData.y]);

            var circle = paper.circle(targetData.x, targetData.y, 15, 15).attr({
                stroke: "none",
                fill: arrayColours[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayColours.length)] //random colour
            });

            //Create our struct
            targetStruct = {
                circle: circle,
                path: path,
                id: targetData.id,
                updated: false
            };

            targetStructArray.push(targetStruct);
        }
        else {
            targetStruct.circle.attr({ cx: targetData.x, cy: targetData.y });
            targetStruct.path.addPart(['L', targetData.x, targetData.y]);
        }

        //ensure we are set as updated
        targetStruct.updated = true;
    }

    //Go through all our existing targets and delete any that werent updated
    for (var i = targetStructArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!targetStructArray[i].updated) {
            targetStructArray[i].circle.remove();
            targetStructArray[i].path.remove();

            targetStructArray[i].circle.removeData();
            targetStructArray[i].path.removeData();

            targetStructArray[i].circle = null;
            targetStructArray[i].path = null;

            targetStructArray[i] = null;
            targetStructArray.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I use two functions not listed here which are [John Resig's Array.Remove](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/) and a Raphael helper function from a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860479/94278)

Comment: I see you updated the code with `itemsToRemove`. The problem is still there: indexes of the `targetStructArray` shift with each `remove`, invalidating the `itemsToRemove`. http://jsfiddle.net/k8WWG/

Comment: Hi @katspaugh - Ive updated my code again based on your original comments. Thanks for the advice... Any ideas on the memory leak?

Comment: Nope. One might suggest not to remove but to reuse the Raphaёl objects.

Comment: @katspaugh I read that too and have implemented it, which makes things better but it still leaks...

Comment: It might not be your code. A few months ago I had a memory leak also and turned out to be a Raphael problem. It was keeping all path data in an array somewhere even tho it was not needed any more. Unfortunately it's been a while so I can't remember the exact problem.

Comment: @zozo if you could remember or find it that would be amazing!! :)

Comment: I remembered a bit... I used http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html to make my own animation. The example itself has a leak. (I remember that I corrected some things so if the example also has another leak except the one from the library I fixed it. Anyway at first view it appears that only the lyb leak is there. I'm looking for the fix now.).